# directly pass the function's return (and call) as another parameter directly in C

Tags: c

I'm wondering if this can be done with pointers, except when I think about it I understand how to pass the function it's self, but not the return.

curious ..

```
int someNum (void) {
  int num = 5;
  return num;
}

int addNum (int num) {
  int addingNum = 1;
  addingNum += num;
  return addingNum;
}
```

.. if this is possible ..

```
int main (void) {
  addNum(sumNum()) 
  return 0;
}
```

.. instead of this

```
int main (void) {
  int num = 0;
  int newNum = 0;
  num = sumNum();
  newNum = addNum(num) 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [C11 Standard - 6.5.2.2 Function calls(p10)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p10) related to *sequence points* and the indeterminate sequencing of function parameters.

Comment: it's a totally normal thing to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is OK to do :

```
int main (void) {
  int newNum = addNum(sumNum()) 
  return 0;
}
```

The result is the same as:

```
int main (void) {
  int num = 0;
  int newNum = 0;
  num = sumNum();
  newNum = addNum(num) 
  return 0;
}
```

Sometimes we write using the first style, sometimes we can use the second style, it depends which one is more readable and easily understanding.